# Timezones, Python and ZeroSeg

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I bought the ZeroSeg. It's a 8-character 7-segment display connected with Raspberry Pi. It uses Python and I can't figure out how to change the timezone. There's a piece of code where the time appears:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
if mode == 1:
        hour = now.hour
        minute = now.minute
        second = now.second
        dot = second % 2 == 0
        # Set hours
        device.letter(1, 8, int(hour / 10))     # Tens
        device.letter(1, 7, hour % 10)     # Ones
        device.letter(1, 6, " ", 1)
        # Set minutes
        device.letter(1, 5, int(minute / 10))   # Tens
        device.letter(1, 4, minute % 10)        # Ones
        device.letter(1, 3, " ", 1)
        # Set seconds
        device.letter(1, 2, int(second / 10))   # Tens
        device.letter(1, 1, second % 10)        # Ones
```

Comment: `datetime.now()` returns a `datetime` object without an associated time zone, in whatever local time is provided by your OS. Do you just want to just offset the displayed time by some arbitrary number of hours or do you actually want to pick the zone from a supplied list?

Comment: Thanks for the thought! The only one thing I had to do was to change the Raspberry Pi timezone.